# how to set same page title for all the my account pages in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to change all the my account page's title to `My Account`.

**For Example:**
If you go to My orders page the title will be `My Orders` by default, but it should be "My Account".

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend to change all of your titles in My Account, however if that's you want then here is how:

Find all files in the `vendor/magento` with name is `customer_account.xml`, the path must looks like `module-*/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`.

For example, My Orders has been set in `module-sales/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Change "My Orders" to whatever you want and repeat it over and over.

Cheers,